# Захват и демонстрация экрана JS

Tags: javascript

Хочу понять возможности захвата или демонстрации экрана для JS. В сервисе krible.ru реализована следующая возможность:

- показывать страницу, которую смотрит оператор
- видеть страницу, которую смотрит клиент
- перемещать посетителя к выделенной части страницы
- можно выделить текст и он будет выделен у клиента

Какими инструментами можно реализовать такие возможности, кто работал с подобным функционалом?
Может быть ссылки на какие-то готовые библиотеки или сайты где можно почитать об этом.

Comment: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: А еще можно ручками транслировать DOM от клиента к оператору, но там столько магии, что лучше в это не лезть

Comment: Есть фича исключительно фаерфокса https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow - позволяет снимать скрины со страницы. Мы использовали в плагине однажды - очень много гемороя сняло. Но вам, боюсь, нужна кроссбраузерность)

Comment: пара ссылок на англоязычную версию:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5621907/1566316
http://stackoverflow.com/q/4912092/1566316

Comment: Всё таки, все ответы ведут на http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ который указал Дмитрий, но я всё же ищу другое решение. Более интересное, чем создание скринов.

Comment: @Vayas, есть еще вариант с трансляцией DOM. Если никто не даст развернутого ответа об этом - напишу сам.

Comment: Хм, судя по задачам - подошла-бы LiveZilla, но если нужно на чистом js - то не вариант

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У меня для вас две новости: хорошая и плохая.

Начну с **плохой**: полностью готовых открытых решений не существует (как минимум они мне не известны).

А **хорошая новость** заключается в том, что существующих свободных инструментов достаточно, чтобы построить необходимое вам решение.

---

Расскажу, как я решал подобную задачу, возможно мой опыт вам чем-то поможет.

Итак, из всех очевидных решений, я предпочел использовать передачу DOM дерева от клиента к оператору и трансляцию сообщений мутаций дерева и пользовательских действий. Этот подход позволяет абстрагироваться от сложности целевого сайта и сделать решение максимально гибким и универсальным.

Всю задачу можно условно разбить на несколько частей:

1. Получить дерево DOM на клиенте и сериализовать его
2. Передать его оператору
3. Восстановить дерево у оператора
4. Подхватывать мутации дерева у клиента и передавать их оператору
5. (Опционально) Передавать пользовательские события (прокрутка, навигация, нажатие клавиш и прочее) от клиента оператору
6. (Опционально) Передавать выделение текста от оператора клиенту

**1. Получение дерева DOM и его сериализация:**

Получение самого дерева - тривиальная задача. Для этого можете использовать стандартный JS DOM API. Начать можно с корневого узла:

```
var root = document;
```

Обходя дочерние элементы этого узла, и выкидывая потенциально проблемные/бесполезные узлы (вроде `<script>` и `<object>`) вы получите подмножество дерева, которое нужно сериализовывать для получения эквивалентной картинки у оператора и клиента.

А вот тут начинается магия: страница с одной и той же разметкой приводи к построению **разного** объектного дерева DOM в разных браузерах. Круче всего ведет себя IE8, создающий по дополнительному текстовому узлу для каждого перевода строки *между* тегами... Но с этой проблемой тоже можно справится. Как именно, рассказывать не буду, проблема довольно обширная.

Как только вы получили подмножество дерева DOM - его нужно сериализовать. Если для каждого узла сохранять его тип, имя а так же атрибуты (если они есть и если тип узла может их содержать) вы можете получить обычный древовидный JSON.

**2. Передача сериализованного дерева оператору**

Тут может быть множество вариантов. Я бы начал с Socket.io, это позволит вам снизить количество головной боли в следующих пунктах.

**3. Восстановить дерево у оператора**

JS позволяет динамически создавать пустые iframe'ы (без атрибутов src) и динамически работать с их содержимым. Имея должным образом сериализованое в JSON дерево восстановить из него объектное дерево DOM - не составляет проблем.

**4. Подхватывать мутации дерева у клиента и передавать их оператору**

Не многие знаю, но в DOM API существует вещь под названием [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Используя его API вы можете динамически подхватывать мутации дерева и передавать его (средствами Socket.io можно делать это в реалтайме) оператору. Опять же, существует отдельная задача сериализации/десериализации изменений, но эту задачу я доверяю вам решить самостоятельно :)

**5. (Опционально) Передавать пользовательские события от клиента оператору**

JS позволяет подвязываться к произвольным событиям окна. Транслировать эти события (умея транслировать координаты узлов) - задача тривиальная.

**6. (Опционально) Передавать выделение текста от оператора клиенту**

Для кроссбраузерной работы с текстовым выделением существует библиотека [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy). Получить и восстановить текстовое выделение с ее использованием не сложно. Самая любопытная задача - правильно рассчитать координаты начала и конца узлов (напоминаю, деревья DOM у оператора и клиента подобны, но не эквивалентны из-за особенностей браузеров). Но эта тема очень обширна и существенно связана с решениями, принятыми вами в предыдущих пунктах. Поэтому вам придется решать эту проблему самостоятельно.

---

Как вы уже могли понять, эта тема очень и очень обширна и она ну совсем не вписывается в формат QA продвигаемый StackOverflow. Тем не менее, вопрос очень интересен, думаю если у вас появятся **конкретные** вопросы, по технологиям упомянутым выше, не стесняйтесь оформлять их отдельными вопросами.

Comment: Как раз на счёт  MutationObserver я не слышал, а в данном случае он нужен как никто другой.) На счёт передачи данных я то же смотрел в сторону веб-сокетов т.к. это самое производительное и простое решение которое мне известно в данный момент.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так:

```
function startCapture(displayMediaOptions) {
 let captureStream = null;

 return navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions)
    .catch(err => { console.error("Error:" + err); return null; });
}
```